# Mapped data is not shown on screen in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mapping

I am getting a response from an API:

```
{
    "data": {
        // other stuff
        "time_breakup": {
            "break_timings": [
                {
                    "break_in_time": "2021-11-18T05:32:35.747Z",
                    "break_out_time": "2021-11-18T05:32:47.871Z"
                },
                {
                    "break_in_time": "2021-11-18T06:21:35.740Z",
                    "break_out_time": "2021-11-18T06:21:39.909Z"
                }
            ],
        },
        
    },
    "success": true
}
```

I am using the below function to get this response:

```
const [shift, setShift]: any = useState();

const getShiftDetails = useCallback(() => {
    ApiFunctions.get('shift/' + ID)
        .then(async resp => {
            if (resp) {
                setShift(resp.data); // saving the response in state
                // some work

            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', resp);
            }
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    getShiftDetails();
}, [getShiftDetails, ID]);
```

So, I have saved the response in a state `shift`. Now I want to map this state to display the time on screen:

```
<View>
    {shift.time_breakup.break_timings.map((item: any, index: any) => {
    console.log(item.break_in_time),
        <>
            <View>
                <Text>{item.break_in_time}</Text>
                <Text>{item.break_out_time}</Text>
            </View>
        </>;
    })}
</View>
```

However, I am not able to see `<Text>{item.break_in_time}</Text>` on screen; and also, in the console, I am getting an infinite loop of time:

console.log:

```
2021-11-18T05:32:35.747Z
2021-11-18T06:21:35.740Z
2021-11-18T05:32:35.747Z
2021-11-18T06:21:35.740Z
2021-11-18T05:32:35.747Z
2021-11-18T06:21:35.740Z
2021-11-18T05:32:35.747Z
...
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- Try adding the `ID` inside the `getShiftDetails` `useCallback` dependencies array.

`const getShiftDetails = useCallback(() => {...}, [ID])` I believe this is what is causing the infinite loop

- Put the `console.log` before **returning** the view from the map function:

```
<View>
    {shift.time_breakup.break_timings.map((item: any, index: any) => {
        console.log(item.break_in_time);
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{item.break_in_time}</Text>
                <Text>{item.break_out_time}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    })}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get infinite loop because on each render your function getShiftDetails gets redefined, React creates a shallow object of it on each render cycle, you can use useCallback to memoize it and Declare ID as dependency array.

Comment: can you show an example on how I can do this

Comment: @pratteekshaurya the other answer by gabriel is the same what i meant with eg.